# How do I make a template conditional based on a collection's size?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I want to do something like this:

```
<template name="list">
  <ul>
  {{#if items}}
      {{#each items}}
        <li>{{itemContents}}</li>
      {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    <li class="placeholder">There are no items in this list.</li>
  {{/if}}
  <ul>
</template>
```

where `items` is a Meteor.cursor:

```
Template.list.items = function() {
  return Items.find();
};
```

However, the code above doesn't work, as the conditional will evaluate positively even if there are no items (which is mildly surprising because Handlebars evaluates `[]` as falsey). I tried changing the condition to

```
{{#if items.count}}
```

but then I get the cryptic error

```
Unknown helper 'items'
```

So, is there a way to write such a condition within a meteor Handlebars template?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This would be the correct way to go:

```
<template name="list">
  <ul>
  {{#each items}}
    <li>{{itemContents}}</li>
  {{else}}
    <li class="placeholder">There are no items in this list.</li>
  {{/each}}
  <ul>
</template>
```

For further information take a look at [handlebarsjs.com](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

*(Meteor uses [Spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md) which is inspired by Handlebars. So the Syntax is almost the same.)*

Comment: shouldn't OP's code work if he declared items like this:
  `Template.list.helpers({
     items: function() {
             return Items.find()
     }
};`

Comment: I don't think so. The problem that he was running into was that `[] !== false`

Answer (score 10):

I was able to get my template to work by using `with` to change the evaluation context:

```
<template name="list">
  <ul>
  {{#with items}}
    {{#if count}}
        {{#each this}}
          <li>{{itemContents}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
      <li class="placeholder">There are no items in this list.</li>
    {{/if}}
  {{/with}}
  <ul>
</template>
```

Notice the modified expressions `{{#if count}}` and `{{#each this}}`.

Answer (score 5):

I have been evaluating Handlebars for the past few weeks and I had a similar issue. What worked for me was reading the length property and adding the else tag.

```
    {{#if competitions.length}}
        <div class="game-score span-4"> 
        ...code goes here...    
        </div>
   {{else}}
        {{> allGameNotes}}
   {{/if}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I get the same error as I do when I try to use `count`. In this case, it would be `Unknown helper 'competitions'.`