# Display template if collection is null or not in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am not sure if this is possible in meteorjs, I have two templates the "register" and the "login". I would like to put a condition where:

If collection is empty
display the register template

if not then display the login template.

Please advise . . thanks a lot.

Comment: [How do I make a template conditional based on a collection's size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040730/how-do-i-make-a-template-conditional-based-on-a-collections-size)

Comment: @Tushar - thank you, let me try to do a test

Comment: The link you provided me also worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a helper function.

HTML:

```
<template name="main">
    {{#if collectionHasItems}}
        {{> login}}
    {{else}}
        {{> register}}
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="register">
    // More code here
</template>

<template name="login">
    // More code here
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.main.helpers({
    collectionHasItems: function() {
        return Collection.find().count();
    }
});
```